# Error in code for finding an element in an array using java

Tags: java, arrays, string, exception, try-catch

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner scn = new Scanner (System.in);
    int n = scn.nextInt();
    int[] arr= new int[n];
    
     
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        arr[i]= scn.nextInt(n);
    }
    int j =  scn.nextInt();
        
       int idx = -1;
       for(int i=0; i<arr.length ; i++){
        if(j==arr[i]){
            idx =i;
            System.out.print(idx);
            break;
        }
        
 }
 System.out.print(idx);

}
}
```

OUTPUT:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "9" under radix 6
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2264)
    at Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

//
HOW TO SOLVE THIS ERROR??

```
1.You are given a number n, representing the size of array a.
2.You are given n distinct numbers, representing elements of array a.
3. You are given another number d.
4. You are required to check if d number exists in the array a and at what index (0 based). If found print the index, otherwise print -1.
```

Input Format
A number n
n1
n2
.. n number of elements
A number d

Output Format
A number representing index at which d is found in array a and -1 if not found

```
Sample Input
6
15
30
40
4
11
9
40

Sample Output
2
```

Comment: change this  arr[i]= scn.nextInt(n); to  arr[i]= scn.nextInt();
n in your code will input the number based on the readix like octal or binary decimal hexdecimal and so on

Comment: What do you think `scn.nextInt(n)` does?